# Print the Retro Rocket

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

*(inspired by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247602/nested-for-loop-art))*

You are given as input a single positive integer *n*.

In as few characters as possible, output a rocket in ASCII art with a head, a tail, and a body composed of *n* segments. There should be no trailing spaces or newlines.

The head and the tail of the rocket are always the same for any value of *n*. The body consists of two different types of segments which alternate. The examples should make the structure of the rocket clear.

Output for *n* = 1:

```
     /**\
    //**\\
   ///**\\\
  ////**\\\\
 /////**\\\\\
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
     /**\
    //**\\
   ///**\\\
  ////**\\\\
 /////**\\\\\
```

Output for *n* = 2:

```
     /**\
    //**\\
   ///**\\\
  ////**\\\\
 /////**\\\\\
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
     /**\
    //**\\
   ///**\\\
  ////**\\\\
 /////**\\\\\
```

Output for *n* = 3:

```
     /**\
    //**\\
   ///**\\\
  ////**\\\\
 /////**\\\\\
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
|\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|.\/\/..\/\/.|
|..\/....\/..|
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
+=*=*=*=*=*=*+
     /**\
    //**\\
   ///**\\\
  ////**\\\\
 /////**\\\\\
```

Comment: related post, from our nemesis: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65040/retro-rocket-ascii-art

Comment: [Also related.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18053609#18053609)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, <s>67</s> 63 characters

```
"дȈ鰚㒄å摒四ㄺ뎞椉ᖛⲠ줥葌⌁掗⦠춻锦䎷겲铣굛쮂먲꿡㦺좒轃汁̕뎕갴瓖邻吟㭰戔蟏㳵回㡚钦״脮烮鋉둎邫"6e4b127b:c~
```

This should work in the [online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

#### How it works

After pushing the Unicode string, the snippet

```
6e4b127b:c~
```

converts the string from base 60000 to base 127, casts to string and evaluates the result.

The code that get executed is the following:

```
"..."          " A binary string of length 42.                                            ";
122b7b         " Convert from base 122 to base 7.                                         ";
"\n *./\|"f=   " Replace each digits with the corresponding character.                    ";
60/~           " Split into chunks of length 60 and dump the resulting array.             ";
               " The stack now contains the rocket's head and a body half.                ";
[_W%[\]_W%]    " Push an array of the body half and the reversed body half, a reversed    ";
               " copy of that array and collect both array into another one.              ";
Nf*Nf+         " Join each array of body halves separating by LFs and append LFs.         ";
ri:I*           " Repeat the resulting array I := int(input()) times.                     ";
I<W%           " Keep the first I bodies and reverse their order.                         ";
\a_@\++        " Prepend and append the rocket head/tail.                                 ";
'+"=*"6*'+N+++ " Push S := '+=*=*=*=*=*=*+\n'.                                            ";
*              " Join the array of parts, separating by S.                                ";
```

Comment: You should really count this in bytes, non?

Comment: @Claudiu: And ruin my score? :P Answers are scored by their length bytes by default, but the question overrides this by saying *in as few characters as possible*.

Answer (score 10):

### CJam, 121 bytes

```
5,{_5\-S*\)_'/*"**"@'\*N}%:A['+"+
"]"=*"6**:Lri:M{M(:M;2,{M+2%:J;3,{:I'|J@2\-'.*I'.*?_J"/\\""\/"?JI)3I-?*\++_+'|N}%}%L}*A
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Takes the input *n* via STDIN.

I'll add an explanation at some point later. Basically it's all just a bunch of loops in a very naive way. To alternate between the two different body parts, I've got a nested loop over the part and a loop over `0` and `1`. Then I just add the outer iterator and the inner one, and use their parity to decide between upwards or downwards pointing triangle.

Comment: I got a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` copy + pasting the code (pointing at `Lri`)

Comment: @Claudiu Did you enter an integer in the "input" field?

Comment: Oh yes, that would do it!

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 203

```ruby
n,q=$*[0].to_i,"\\/"
h,r,m=1.upto(5).map{|i|(?/*i+"**"+?\\*i).center 14},?++"=*"*6+?+,3.times.map{|i|?|+?.*i+q*(3-i)+?.*(2*i)+q*(3-i)+?.*i+?|}*"\n"
p=m.reverse.tr q,"/\\"
puts h,([r,m,p,r,p,m]*n)[0,3*n],r,h
```

### Ungolfed

I think in this case it's beneficial to have an non-golfed version.

```ruby
n      = $*[0].to_i
head   = 1.upto(5).map { |i| ("/"*i + "**" + "\\"*i).center 14 }
ridge  = "+" + "=*"*6 + "+"
middle = 3.times.map { |i| "|" + "."*i + "\\/"*(3-i) + "."*(2*i) + "\\/"*(3-i) + "."*i + "|" }.join "\n"
piddle = middle.reverse.tr "\\/", "/\\"

puts head
puts ([ridge,middle,piddle,ridge,piddle,middle]*n)[0,3*n]
puts ridge, head
```

### Explanation

I doubt this is anywhere near efficient, but it was fun nonetheless.

- Input is taken from `ARGV`.
- `h` contains the "head" and "tail" of the rocket, `r` contains the "ridges" that separate the different parts of the rocket and `m` and `p` are the top and bottom parts of the "body" of the rocket.
- The body is constructed by cycling through the `Array` `["ridge", "top of body", "bottom of body", "ridge", "bottom of body", "top of body"]` and taking the first `3*n` elements.
- `puts` makes sure everything gets its own line.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 120 + 77 + 1 = 198 characters

This ended up being the wrong approach, but I had already finished when Martin posted his answer.

```
H,L,T,B=open("R","rb").read().decode('zip').split("X")
n=input()
for p in[H]+([B,T,L,T,B,L]*n)[:3*n][::-1]+[L,H]:print p
```

Requires a file `R` (+1 for filename) of 77 bytes, which you can generate as follows:

```
>>> open('R','wb').write('eJxNjMENwDAIA/+ZIm8i4Qm6Bw+PwvDFQRUFydwJwd5VMOO6ILqIRjE+LsEI4zw2fSKJ6Vzpmt4p\ndVlnRikoVWqrK+8s/X1ivozIJuo=\n'.decode('base64'))
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (E6) 252 <s>257</s>

Overuse of string.repeat

```
F=p=>{
  R=(n,s='.',a='')=>a+s.repeat(n)+a;
  for(i=f=o=m=n='';++i<6;)
    o+=f+R(6-i,' ')+R(i,u='/')+'**'+R(i,t='\\'),
    f='\n',
    i<4?m+=f+R(2,R(4-i,t+u,R(i-1)),'|',n+=f+R(2,R(i,u+t,R(3-i)),'|')):0;
  s=f+R(6,'=*','+'),
  console.log(o+s+R(p&1,q=m+n+s)+R(p/2,n+m+s+q)+f+o)
}
```

Comment: it's fun, we both have 252b but with completely different approaches :)

Answer (score 3):

### JS, WIP, 252b or 173 chars

It's not a function, so you have to set the value of n at the beginning (3 here), then execute it in the console or in nodeJS.

Here's the 252b version:

```
n=3;r=a="     /**01    //**001   ///**0001  ////**00001 /////**00000";b="1+=*=*=*=*=*=*+1";for(c=[d="|0/0/0/0/0/0/|1|.0/0/..0/0/.|1|..0/....0/..|",d.split("").reverse().join("")];n--;)r+=b+c[n%2]+1+c[1-n%2];(r+b+a).replace(/0/g,"\\").replace(/1/g,"\n")
```

And here's the 173 chars version (using http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/)

```
n=3;eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Comment: Tested in console. Cool and +1, but usually when the OP asks for an output and not a just return value, an output statement is requested (like console.log or alert - I don't know in nodeJS).

Comment: you're right... I allowed myself to consider the console as an output. :p (also, nodeJS can only output on its console afaik)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES3): 243 <s>219</s> bytes

```
R=function(n){for(a='',i=5;i--;t=a+=s+'\n')for(s='**',j=6;j--;b=['|../\\..|./\\/\\.|/\\/\\/\\','|\\/\\/\\/|.\\/\\/.|..\\/..'])s=i<j?'/'+s+'\\':' '+s+' ';for(;a+='+=*=*=*=*=*=*+\n',n;)a+=(b[n&1]+b[--n&1]).replace(/[^|]+/g,'$&$&|\n');return a+t}
```

Comment: 1:`SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`, 2:incorrect output, the body segments ahould not be all equal (odd and even are different)

Comment: 1. That's because it's intended to be FunctionExpression. But I've added an assignment, so it should work now.
2. Thanks! I didn't notice that at first.